# Как в mysql скопировать из строки 0 символов?

Tags: mysql, sql

Хочу сделать, что бы в одно запросе, проверялось условие, и в зависимости от этого, строка принимала, то или иное, значение.

Вот пример с числовыми значениями

```
UPDATE table SET intValue = 
(5 * CAST(a>b AS SIGNED INTEGER)) 
+ 
(21 * CAST(a<=b AS SIGNED INTEGER))
WHERE active = "1"
```

Я хочу сделать тоже самое со строкой, копируя из нее, если условие выполнилось всю строку, а если не выполнилось 0 символов, пробую так

```
UPDATE table SET strValue = 
SUBSTRING("vasia", 1, LENGTH("vasia") * CAST(a>b AS SIGNED INTEGER)) 
+ 
SUBSTRING("petia", 1, LENGTH("petia") * CAST(a<=b AS SIGNED INTEGER)) 
WHERE active = "1"
```

в таблицу записывается "0", хотя одно из условий точно выполнилось

UPD

Решил сделать так

```
UPDATE table SET strValue = ELT(CAST(a<=b AS SIGNED INTEGER) + 1, "vasia", "petia")
```

Comment: оператор `+` складывает числа, поэтому ваши строки преобразуются к числам и становятся нулем, так как чисел в начале не содержат. для конкатенации строк используется функция `concat()`

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать, пока просматривал concat нашел ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: Кстати, CAST не нужен, только сравнение в скобки заключить. В MySQL сравнение возвращает именно число 0 или 1, а не булеву величину. А еще можно написать просто `IF(a<=b,"petia","vasia")`